# TYPO3: show user input in front-end

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a little problem with TYPO3, i have a navbar (fluid) and want to show a number in there which the user should be able to fill in in the Backend.
I would like to use a typoscript variable to show this number but my question is:
Is there a easy way that a user can input a number which I am able to read in my typoscript without editing the CONSTANTS in the template editor? Like some way the user can input this number in the PAGE section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a text content element on a page and/or in a column that is not being shown on your webpage and then add it to Typoscript like this:

```
10 = CONTENT
10 {
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.pidInList = 58
  select.where = colPos=3
}
```

Where `58` is the ID of the page your content element is on, and `colPos=3` is the number of the column (in this case, `3` is the "Border"-column)